# Export Table to CSV, with commas not newlines

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a function `f[a]`. I run it through `Table` to generate a huge list of values for later use in a C program as a lookup table. I want to export this to CSV so I can copy/paste it into my code editor and quickly turn it into a C array (all I'd have to do is wrap it in curly braces and give it a name):

```
Export["myfile.csv", Table[ f[a], {a, 0, 6} ], "CSV" ];
```

What I want is this:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

and so on, but I end up with this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Each entry is on a new line. What simple, obvious thing have I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Your C-compiler won't mind this format, so what's your problem?

Comment: Yes it would. There are no commas in the output, so I'd have to load up the file, replace \n with ,\n and then save it. I don't want to do that when I have a tool that's perfectly capable of doing the job for me. Also, I'm generating a lot of lookup tables so I'd like to automate all of the process if possible.

Comment: OK, I misread your original question. Please see my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd. Have edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could export using the more general ["Table" format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Table.html) and specify the line separators. For example:

```
Export["myfile.csv", Table[f[a], {a, 0, 6}], "Table", "LineSeparators" -> ", "]

FilePrint["myfile.csv"]
(* Returns: 
f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6]
*)
```

You might also need to specify the `"FieldSeparators"` option, it's default for the `"Table"` format is `"\t"`.

Comment: 10 pts closer to your 10K :-)

Comment: Aha! I *knew* there'd be another way! Thanks. Sorry Yoda but Simon's answer is more generalised (and he's so close to 10k...); I have got to accept this one really.

Comment: @TimKemp No worries :) Simon's answer certainly is better.

Comment: @yoda: Actually, my preference is for the construction Mr.Wizard used. That would be the way I would go about it. I only posted this to show a solution that didn't use the explicit `"CSV"` export format.

Answer (score 6):

If your export object is a single list, you can avoid modifying its elements, and just wrap it in `List`:

```
Export["myfile.csv", List @ Table[f[a], {a, 0, 6}]]
```

Comment: A bit cleaner than using Transpose. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim, I could have worded my answer better, because there is no reason to avoid `Transpose`, but rather, avoid having to change your Table object.

Comment: @Tim Tables are 2D structures.  In CSV, the row separator is a new line, while the column separator is a comma.  So indeed, this one could be called the canonical solution.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want:

```
Export["myfile.csv", Transpose@Table[{f@a}, {a, 0, 6}], "CSV"]
```

Your approach will result in a column vector, which leads to each row being written out on a new line. Creating the table as a row vector solves this problem. In this case, each column is separated by a comma.

---

Creating a list of lists seems a klunky way to do it, but that's how Mathematica treats it internally anyway. If you import the CSV file from your code in the question:

```
Import["myfile.csv"]
Out[1]={{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}
```

you see that Mathematica has automatically stuffed each element into a list. So it will have to be stuffed in a list, either this way or as in [Mr.Wizard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8302737/616736).

Comment: It does, thanks, and it solves my immediate problem. It feels a bit kludgy to just stuff the list inside another one in order to exploit how Export works. Do you mind if I wait a bit before accepting to see if anything else comes in? There's usually a few ways in M of getting things done and I'd really like to see if there are alternatives here. +1 anyway as it does work :)

Comment: Thanks Yoda, glad you understand.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `Partition`?

```
f[x_] = Sin[x/10.];

Export["C:\\Users\\Sjoerd\\Desktop\\myfile.csv",
       Partition[Table[f[a], {a, 0, 600}], 30], 
       "CSV"
];
```

[image]

Comment: Using Partition with a value of 1 has the same effect as yoda and Mr. Wizard's solution. Interesting to see another way of getting to it, thanks. If I was going to Excel then this would be very useful to fit to a x columns wide.

Comment: @Tim Excel was just used as an example. If anyone would ever have the need to examine the data file (for instance, from within your IDE) it would also be more compact on the screen. That would be my main reason of using this.

Comment: Sjoerd, the problem with that approach is that it doesn't insert a comma after each partitioned sublist - ie, the newlines are just newlines, not newlines plus commas. I need a comma after every entry.